# Bind the Azure Emulator to all addresses of its host?

Tags: azure, azure-emulator

Is it possible to bind the Azure Emulator to all of the addresses on the host? The default configuration binds the emulator to a single address, the loopback address - 127.0.0.1.

I can successfully change the *single* address that it binds to in its config file:

```
%Program Files%\Microsoft SDKs\Windows Azure\Emulator\devfabric\DevFC.exe.config
```

By changing `VipPoolStartIPAddress` and `VipPoolEndIPAddress`:

```
<add key="VipPoolStartIPAddress" value="192.168.1.130" />
<add key="VipPoolEndIPAddress" value="192.168.1.130" />
```

What I want to do, however, is bind the emulator to all of the addresses on the host. I've tried a bunch of unfruitful configurations:

- `*`
- `*.*.*.*`
- `0.0.0.0`
- `empty`

Could this really be impossible in v2.3?

Thanks,
Pete

Comment: I'm aware that workarounds exist to route all traffic from other adapters to the loopback adapter, but those are irrelevant to my question.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to do this other than, as you mentioned in your comment, to redirect other traffic to your loopback adapter.  This has been the by-design behavior since SDK 1.0.

Comment: Thanks @kwill, does Microsoft document this by-design limitation anywhere? Being unable to connect our mobile applications to a development environment on a shared code base is quite the painful limitation. It's kind of surprising given the nature of azure.