# Azure Emulator with Full IIS

Tags: c#, iis, azure, iis-express

It was feasible in Azure SDK 1.7 but now it uses IIS Express.
My cloud service is consumed by other application within LAN. I wish to expose my development emulator to the consuming application. So that it could test locally.

Currently I have to publish to cloud & do remote debugging to find issues.

Although I have been able to expose IIS Express [using this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3313616/iis-express-enable-external-request) but every time I restart emulator, my IIS express custom changes are lost.

Is there a work-around to tell azure emulator to use full IIS?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the properties for the cloud service project go to the Web settings and then switch the Emulator settings from 'Use Emulator Express' to 'Use Full Emulator'.  After this the Local Development Server options will enable you to choose 'Use IIS Web Server'.

Comment: Thanks Kwill, your answer solved the question. I presumed once azure services run in IIS, it would serve all requests from LAN, if I open firewall on port.

Comment: That is correct, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24591302/bind-the-azure-emulator-to-all-addresses-of-its-host/24591997#24591997 for more information.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Screen shot from visual studio. You DO NOT have to use IIS for the emulator]

Screen shot from visual studio. You DO NOT have to use IIS for the emulator